# What is it called if two versions of a program performs the same job, but does it using different code?

Tags: theory, computation-theory

> What is it called if two versions of a program performs the same job, but does it using different code?

Is it correct to say that the two versions are semantically equivalent, although the versions may consist of different code?

Say, I've some goal to accomplish and both program versions performs the job. Is there a term for expression this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call this [*extensional equivalence.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality) Two programs are *extensionally equivalent* if they do the same thing, but are possibly implemented in a different manner. However, note that each program is always extensionally equivalent to itself as extensional equivalence is an equivalence relation.